# Count indices in summation

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

Consider a summation of the form
\begin{equation}\sum_{i_1,\cdots, i_L=1}^K f_{i_1,\cdots, i_L}.\end{equation}
How many sums of, say, $\ell$ distinct indices are present?

The problem can be alternatively stated as follows: suppose to have an $L$-dimensional vector. The generic element is an integer between $1$ and $K$. There are, therefore, $K^L$ of such vectors. Now fix an integer number $\ell$. How many vectors have exactly $\ell$ distinct elements?

I think the problem is strictly related to bins and balls problems, coupon collector problem and similar. But I didn't find the solution till now.

Thanks fot the help!

Comment: I think inclusion-exclusion principle might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are asking for the number of functions from a set of L
elements to one of K elements such that the image of the maps have l elements. The number of possible images is the binomial coefficient of K over l. This number is multiplied by the number of surjective maps from a set of L objects to a set of l objects which is the Stirling number of the second kind S(L,l). There is a standard explicit formula for the Stirling numbers of the second kind which can be derived using the Principle of Inclusions and Exclusions as mentioned by the previous commenter.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a pen and writing paper. The formula for the Stirling Number of the second kind S(n,k) is Sigma(j=0 to k)(-1)^j bin(k,j) (k-j)^n . To derive it use the Principle of Inclusions and Exclusions (Bachet's Formula). Let Ai be the set of all maps from a set of n elements to a set of k elements which miss the ith element of the codomain. The number of such maps is (k-1)^n . The intersection of Ai1 and Ai2 for i1<>i2 has (k-2)^n elements etc.
Apply Bachet's formula to calculate the number of maps in the union of the Ai to get the number of non-surjective maps and then subtract from k^n to get the number of surjective maps.